# Adding tags to mp3 with eyed3 results in no change

Tags: python, tags, mp3, addition, urllib

I am trying to add tags (title, genre, etc.) to a mp3 file downloaded created with urllib in Python. Using eye3d and the example from their website, the program runs without any errors, but doesn't seem to do anything. When checking the details of the file, title, artist and everything else stays empty as it was before.

Using this example:

```
import eyed3

audiofile = eyed3.load("song.mp3")
audiofile.tag.artist = u"Nobunny"
audiofile.tag.album = u"Love Visions"
audiofile.tag.album_artist = u"Various Artists"
audiofile.tag.title = u"I Am a Girlfriend"
audiofile.tag.track_num = 4

audiofile.tag.save()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Is song.mp3 in the same directory as your python script?...

Comment: eyeD3 supports ID3 version 2.2 in read-only mode, check your mp3 ID3 version: `eyeD3 song.mp3`

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Yes, it is.

Comment: @Delimitry `print audiofile.tag.version` returns `(2, 4, 0)`

Comment: What Python version are u using?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Oh, 2.7, sorry for not clarifying that. But yes, 2.7, as recommended.

Comment: How do i convert the tag version from v2.4 to v2.3 ? i cant find any help on this

Comment: @BonifacePereira, you can define version during saving tag, i.e. `audiofile.tag.save(version=(2, 3, 0))` or if you create tag from scratch during tag initialization, i.e. `audiofile.initTag(version=(2, 3, 0))`. I used this approach in my script with `0.9.6` version of *eyeD3*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was to add the file's path in the save() function:

```
    audiofile.tag.save(fileName)
```

In your example fileName would be "song.mp3".

Answer (score 0):

Your mp3 file might has no tags at all, you shout initialize it first:

```py
audiofile = eyed3.load("song.mp3")
audiofile.initTag()
...
```

Or create tag with specific version, for example:

```py
audiofile.initTag(version=(2, 3, 0))  # v2.4 by default
```